# Understanding Array::splice in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I am trying to remove an object from an array, but for some reason it's not working. I am under the impression that a splice accepts 2 parameters: first, the position in the array to begin at. And for parameter 2, how many to delete from then on out.

I just want to delete one entry so I am doing this:

```
array.splice(i,0);
```

But it isn't working. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and enlighten me on how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm also not happy about [`array.splice`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice())

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to remove one element, you call `splice(index, 1)`.

Answer (score 7):

Your code will delete zero things is what you are describing. Change the second parameter to a `1`:

```
array.splice(i,1);
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do two thing with splice method.

1. To delete the first element from array.
   arrayName.splice(index,no of element)

   i.e myArr.splice(0,1); //it's delete first element from array

   Note: Array index start from 0,1,2 and so on....
2. To add element into array.
   arrayName.splice(index to add,0,elem1,elem2)
   i.e. myArr.splice(0,0,"A","B"); 
   Note:it add A,B into myArr start from zero position and shift the existing element's   index no.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to remove the **first** item from an array is using `shift()`

```
myArray.shift();
```

You can add an item on the beginning of the array too using `unshift()`.

```
myArray.unshift( item );
```